# App crashes instantly when running on android

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I tried to use buildozer to make an apk out of a python/kivy program. It runs nicely on my mac but when I create an apk file for my android smartphone it instantly crashes without any message.

To find the error I tried to do the same with a simple "hello world" program. This one also crashes instantly. On a different phone I had the same result.

Here is part of my buildozer log-file.

```
> WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated
> and does nothing. No compiled python is present to zip, skipping. No
> setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
> Applying Java source code patches... Applying patch:
> src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch Warning: failed to apply patch
> (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied:
> src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
> # Android packaging done!
> # APK myapp__armeabi-v7a-1.0-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk available in the bin directory
> # Run '/Users/jeffreyschuster/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
> devices'
> # Cwd None List of devices attached
> 
> # Application pushed.
> # Application started.
> # Search for Git (git)
> #  -> found at /usr/bin/git
> # Search for Cython (cython)
> #  -> found at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/cython
> # Search for Java compiler (javac)
> #  -> found at /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/javac
> # Search for Java keytool (keytool)
> #  -> found at /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/keytool
```

The program itself is the following (simple example from the internet)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Lesson1App(App):
    def build(self):
        lbl=Label(text='Hello World!') 
        return lbl

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    Lesson1App().run()
```

Any ideas why it crashes?

After connecting my phone and using the command with `deploy` etc. it still ends up the same. Here is the new logfile:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YQssyT-5vMhb44d8JRMj3nRIycRFhdpf

I hope this link works properly

Ok, I found out that I have to set some some things on my phone. Now the installation seems to work but the app still crashes.

On the phone I get the same error message like when I install it manually:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qokHo.jpg)

Comment: Never guess why things crash, [debug it](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform).

Comment: As suggested in the [documentation](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#run-my-application), try running `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt` after connecting your phone to your PC.

Comment: This is not my_log.txt ... please add the result of logcat

Comment: @thomas You are right, something went wrong. I tried it again and the new my_log.txt is linked now. Thanks for telling me!

Comment: I get 404 when opening your dropbox-link

Comment: @thomas please try this google drive link

Comment: Could read the Logfile, but the start of the apk is missing .. please try: adb logcat -d > logcat.txt and afterwards start the App and stop adb and post the file

Comment: @thomas ok, not sure if I did it correctly but here is the link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Jpa0h2qGlHH_KoJv8eH_HTn7zHImFGi7

Comment: Now the content which is needed to check is included .. after line 01-15 09:59:21.781  1672  2124 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=org.kivy.android.PythonActivity flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.simpletest.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} from uid 2000

Comment: Think at this step I can't help you ... probably you buildozer.ini file is wrong