# What is or How to Diagnose SDL Error: Could not load any libpythonXXX.so on Android phones after Buildozer Build

Tags: python, android, linux, kivy, buildozer

I've successfully built a simple (ish) 'Hello World app' using Kivy and Buildozer. Having downloaded the apk to various android phones (android 5 and 10, Samsung j3 & another newer Samsung phone who's model number currently escapes me, but is only 2 years old) and after a successful install when I open the app I get the following error (after the splash screen deploys/loads):

> SDL2 Error: An error occurred while trying to start the application. Please try again and/or reinstall. Error: Could not load any **libpythonXXX.so**

I have looked at this [post but there's no answer](https://groups.google.com/g/kivy-dev/c/o-ahibVo4KA/m/g7wgicfNAAAJ), tried [this on github](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/2056) and [this doesn't work either](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1010). [Unfortunately this SO post is no help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69325500/why-is-there-error-buildozer-debug-and-sdl-2). And I assume [this post is referring to the Kivy version which also doesn't make any difference](https://forum.autosportlabs.com/viewtopic.php?p=26728)

Currently building on 64 bit linux mate 19.3

It runs on Kivy fine.

What follows are main.py the .kv file and buildozer.spec:

main.py:

```python
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

import random

# I've tried with Kivy 2.0.0 too
kivy.require('1.9.1')

class MyRoot(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyRoot, self).__init__()

    def generate_num(self):
        self.ids.random_label.text = str(random.randint(0, 1000))

class TestRandom(App):

    def build(self):
       return MyRoot()



tr = TestRandom()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tr.run()
```

testrandom.kv

```python
# really need those angle brackets and in the right place
<MyRoot>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        # rndom_label: rndom_label

        Label:
            text: "Loz's Random Test"
            font_size: 64
            # normalised colour values
            color: (.80, .45, .20, 1)
        Label:
            id: random_label
            text: '-'
            font_size: 30
            color: (0, .5, 1, 1)
        Button:
            text: 'Generate'
            font_size: 32
            size: 100, 50
            on_press: root.generate_num()
```

Buildozer.spec: I've adjusted the target spec depending on what architecture I was building for **armeabi-v7a** for android 5 and **arm64-v8a** for the later version.
The python version is 3.6.9, which is the same as my system currently has, this allows the package to build and to [avoid all those cython errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65462530/pyclipper-installation-error-tp-print-is-not-a-member-of-typeobject).

```python
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Lozs Random Generator 2

# (str) Package name
package.name = lozRGapp2

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 3

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3==3.6.9, hostpython3==3.6.9, kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use, I've adjusted to reflect main.py
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
android.presplash_color = fuchsia

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 28

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 24

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk =  25

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path = /home/hp-350/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r23b

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path = /home/hp-350/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Android Activity
# use that parameter together with android.entrypoint to set custom Java class instead of PythonActivity
#android.activity_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest> element of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML code
#android.extra_manifest_xml = ./src/android/extra_manifest.xml

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest><application> tag of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML arguments:
#android.extra_manifest_application_arguments = ./src/android/extra_manifest_application_arguments.xml

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Python Service
# use that parameter to set custom Java class instead of PythonService
#android.service_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonService

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk assets directory.
# Either form may be used, and assets need not be in 'source.include_exts'.
# 1) android.add_assets = source_asset_relative_path
# 2) android.add_assets = source_asset_path:destination_asset_relative_path
#android.add_assets =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
#android.enable_androidx = False

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
#android.logcat_pid_only = False

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
# In past, was `android.arch` as we weren't supporting builds for multiple archs at the same time.
android.archs = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
#android.allow_backup = True

# (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
# android.backup_rules =

# (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
# you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
# This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
# Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
# android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

# (bool) disables the compilation of py to pyc/pyo files when packaging
# android.no-compile-pyo = True

# (str) The format used to package the app for release mode (aab or apk or aar).
# android.release_artifact = aab

# (str) The format used to package the app for debug mode (apk or aar).
# android.debug_artifact = apk

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
#p4a.url =

# (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = develop

# (str) python-for-android specific commit to use, defaults to HEAD, must be within p4a.branch
#p4a.commit = HEAD

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false

# (str) extra command line arguments to pass when invoking pythonforandroid.toolchain
#p4a.extra_args =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
#ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
#ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
#ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
#ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
#ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) The development team to use for signing the debug version
#ios.codesign.development_team.debug = <hexstring>

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

# (str) The development team to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.development_team.release = <hexstring>

# (str) URL pointing to .ipa file to be installed
# This option should be defined along with `display_image_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.app_url =

# (str) URL pointing to an icon (57x57px) to be displayed during download
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.display_image_url =

# (str) URL pointing to a large icon (512x512px) to be used by iTunes
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `display_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.full_size_image_url =


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .aab, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a simple fix for this, am I missing something obvious ? For example, I had many build errors, sometimes it was just a case of installing a missing library or getting my python versions correct in the buildozer.spec. I'm not suggesting that these might be the solution, just that the solution might be in the 'same order of complexity' i.e. relatively simple.
2. If it's not something simple, what would be a good way to go about starting to diagnose this kind of problem, at a guess, installing some kind of android development tools and going from there ?

[I am currently trying out some diagnostics based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740116/app-crashes-instantly-when-running-on-android)

Comment: After a couple  months, the solution for me has been to ditch python, kivy & buildozer and learn Android Studio and kotlin. I took me a month to get to the stage where I was asking this question, I couldn't get a solution so ditched the whole enterprise. I've been more productive on Android Studio and am producing working (simple) apps after 6 weeks, which was about the time I spent getting nowhere with Kivy etc. As far as I understand it Python isn't really the 'right tool' to develop for Android. I don't wish to 'do down' the Kivy framework, it just didn't turn out to be right for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have been dealing with this issue for a couple of days and I just wanted to post the solution that I have found. It is really not that obvious so hopefully it helps others.

first it appears that the issue is not with Buildozer but with the package python-for-android that Buildozer relies on (and is actually not really an 'issue' but more of an update timing thing).

There is a java method in this file:
pythonforandroid/bootstraps/common/build/src/main/java/org/kivy/android/PythonUtil.java

here:
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android

that checks for a certain python version, based on your kivy/buildozer target python version and python-for-android's current supported python version on their 'main' branch.

This is from the 'develop' branch but at the time of writing this the 'main' branch is only supporting python == 3.9

```
public static void loadLibraries(File filesDir, File libsDir) {
boolean foundPython = false;

for (String lib : getLibraries(libsDir)) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Loading library: " + lib);
    try {
        System.loadLibrary(lib);
        if (lib.startsWith("python")) {
            foundPython = true;
        }
    } catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        // If this is the last possible libpython
        // load, and it has failed, give a more
        // general error
        Log.v(TAG, "Library loading error: " + e.getMessage());
        if (lib.startsWith("python3.10") && !foundPython) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not load any libpythonXXX.so");
        } else if (lib.startsWith("python")) {
            continue;
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "An UnsatisfiedLinkError occurred loading " + lib);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

SO in your buildozer.spec file you can specify which branch of python-for-android to use (shortened to p4a in the spec file)

which is this line

## (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master

#p4a.branch = master

uncomment the p4a.branch line and change that to 'develop'. Again this is for the time of writing, the develop branch supports up to python 3.10 and the 'main' (or i guess 'master') supports up to 3.9

Comment: Upvoted your answer because it looks like a good answer, and you've taken the time to answer something that may be a difficult question. However I can't accept this as the accepted answer (at least not now) because I have no idea if it works. Referencing my comment in the above question, I've moved on to a different environment and am in the process of doing a system upgrade. I'm not sure it's an issue I can even now replicate even if I wanted to, and I'd like to check the answer works before accepting it and I now can't. Thanks for investigating what seems to be a 'fringe' issue though.